# texstudio macro for next or previous label

Tags: macros, texstudio

In texstudio there exist two menus by which one can add the \ref{} with reference previous or next label. 
However, the usage of such a command is more encountered when referencing to equations, where the \eqref{} should be applied instead. Therefore, it would be more appropriate if it inserts the key of the next or previous label.

Ex. consider the case:

```
\begin{equation} \label{ZEqnNum448683} 
\begin{array}{l} {\mathop{\min }\limits_{x} \mathop{\sum }\limits_{k}^{} |y_{k}^{+} -y_{k}^{-} |+|z_{k}^{+} -z_{k}^{-} |} 
\end{array} \end{equation}
```

I need a shortcut to insert just the key, i.e. ZEqnNum448683 into my text when writing above or bellow this equation.

Comment: `\mathop{\min }` should be `\min` and  `\mathop{\sum }` should be `\sum` (they are mathop already) you only need `\limits` here as `array` is being used instead of a multi-line math display environment such as `align`

Comment: Thank you. they were generated by MathType I really don't follow what it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

### Insert Key of Next Label:

```
%SCRIPT
var LineNo = cursor.lineNumber(), ColNo = cursor.columnNumber();
cursor.movePosition(1,cursorEnums.End, cursorEnums.KeepAnchor);
var myText = cursor.selectedText();
var regEx = /\\label{(.*)}/
var match = regEx.exec(myText);

cursor.moveTo(LineNo, ColNo);
if (match && match[1]){
    editor.insertText(match[1])
}
```

### Insert Key of Previous Label:

```
%SCRIPT
var LineNo = cursor.lineNumber(), ColNo = cursor.columnNumber();
cursor.movePosition(1,cursorEnums.Start, cursorEnums.KeepAnchor);
var myText = cursor.selectedText();
var regEx = /\\label{(.*)}/
var match = regEx.exec(myText);

cursor.moveTo(LineNo, ColNo);
if (match && match[1]){
    editor.insertText(match[1])
}
```

Assign these to their own respective keyboard shortcuts. In the gif below, I show briefly how to implement these two macros. (Under `Macros -> Edit Macros -> Add`)

### Test MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{BeforeLabel} 
    x = y
\end{equation}

% Test here:
\eqref{} % Next key
\eqref{} % Previous key

\begin{equation}\label{AfterLabel} 
    a = b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: my gif]